# simple CUDA vector searching/indexing program not working correctly

Tags: c++, cuda

I seem to be having some problems with a CUDA program I'm trying to write. The idea is to add two arrays of random numbers then log an index of ones above a certain value. I've had the program run fine, then when i change the threshold value and recompile its as if that value wasn't changed. I have an sh for compiling which deletes the original executable and .o files. I'm new to CUDA so maybe its something simple like a compilation problem or maybe im not unlocking the memory correctly. I release the arrays on both the device and host but I'm not sure how to release the two floats i declared on the device.
Any help would be greatly appreciated Thanks in advance

specs: nvidia gt220 on 340.93 driver CUDA 6.5

Heres kernel.cu

```
#include <cuda_runtime.h> 
#include <stdio.h>

__device__ void my_push_back(int gg, float *index, int num)
{
int insert_pt = atomicAdd(&dev_count, 1);
  if (insert_pt < num)
  {
  index[insert_pt] = gg;
  }
}

__device__ int dev_count = 0;

__global__ void
vectorAdd(const float *A, const float *B, float *C, float *index, int numElements)
{
int i = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
float dev_value = 1.990;
float dev_value2 = 2.000;

  if (i < numElements)
  {
  C[i] = A[i] + B[i];
  float temp = C[i];
    if(temp > dev_value && temp < dev_value2)
    {
    my_push_back(i, index, numElements);

    }

  }
}


void kernel_wrap(float *h_A, float *h_B, float *h_C, float *h_Index, int numElements)
{
// Error code to check return values for CUDA calls
cudaError_t err = cudaSuccess;
size_t size = numElements * sizeof(float);
// Print the vector length to be used, and compute its size


//now allocate memory on device GPU
    // Allocate the device input vector A
    float *d_A = NULL;
    err = cudaMalloc((void **)&d_A, size);

    if (err != cudaSuccess)
    {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate device vector A (error code %s)!\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Allocate the device input vector B
    float *d_B = NULL;
    err = cudaMalloc((void **)&d_B, size);

    if (err != cudaSuccess)
    {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate device vector B (error code %s)!\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Allocate the device output vector C
    float *d_C = NULL;
    err = cudaMalloc((void **)&d_C, size);

    if (err != cudaSuccess)
    {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate device vector C (error code %s)!\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    float *d_Index = NULL;
    err = cudaMalloc((void **)&d_Index, size);

    if (err != cudaSuccess)
    {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate device vector C (error code %s)!\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Copy the host input vectors A and B in host memory to the device input vectors in
    // device memory
    printf("Copy input data from the host memory to the CUDA device\n");
    err = cudaMemcpy(d_A, h_A, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    if (err != cudaSuccess)
    {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to copy vector A from host to device (error code %s)!\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    err = cudaMemcpy(d_B, h_B, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    if (err != cudaSuccess)
    {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to copy vector B from host to device (error code %s)!\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

// Launch the Vector Add CUDA Kernel
int threadsPerBlock = 256;
int blocksPerGrid =(numElements + threadsPerBlock - 1) / threadsPerBlock;
printf("CUDA kernel launch with %d blocks of %d threads\n", blocksPerGrid, threadsPerBlock);
vectorAdd<<<blocksPerGrid, threadsPerBlock>>>(d_A, d_B, d_C, d_Index, numElements);
err = cudaGetLastError();

if (err != cudaSuccess)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to launch vectorAdd kernel (error code %s)!\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

//Retrieve data from GPU memeory

// Copy the device result vector in device memory to the host result vector
// in host memory.
printf("Copy output data from the CUDA device to the host memory\n");
err = cudaMemcpy(h_C, d_C, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

if (err != cudaSuccess)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to copy vector C from device to host (error code %s)!\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

    printf("Copy output data from the CUDA device to the host memory\n");
err = cudaMemcpy(h_Index, d_Index, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

if (err != cudaSuccess)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to copy vector C from device to host (error code %s)!\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

//Free up memeory on GPU

// Free device global memory
err = cudaFree(d_A);

if (err != cudaSuccess)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to free device vector A (error code %s)!\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

err = cudaFree(d_B);

if (err != cudaSuccess)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to free device vector B (error code %s)!\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

err = cudaFree(d_C);

if (err != cudaSuccess)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to free device vector C (error code %s)!\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

 err = cudaFree(d_Index);

if (err != cudaSuccess)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to free device vector C (error code %s)!\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}


// Free host memory



// Reset the device and exit
// cudaDeviceReset causes the driver to clean up all state. While
// not mandatory in normal operation, it is good practice.  It is also
// needed to ensure correct operation when the application is being
// profiled. Calling cudaDeviceReset causes all profile data to be
// flushed before the application exits
err = cudaDeviceReset();

if (err != cudaSuccess)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to deinitialize the device! error=%s\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

printf("Done\n");
```

}

And heres main.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>

extern void kernel_wrap(float *h_A, float *h_B, float *h_C, float *h_Index, int numElements);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

int numElements = 50000;
size_t size = numElements * sizeof(float);
printf("[Vector addition of %d elements]\n", numElements);

//allocate memeory of vectors

// Allocate the host input vector A
float *h_AA = (float *)malloc(size);

// Allocate the host input vector B
float *h_BB = (float *)malloc(size);

// Allocate the host output vector C
float *h_CC = (float *)malloc(size);

float *h_Indexx = (float *)malloc(size);

// Verify that allocations succeeded
if (h_AA == NULL || h_BB == NULL || h_CC == NULL || h_Indexx == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate host vectors!\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

//create intial values for A and B

// Initialize the host input vectors
for (int i = 0; i < numElements; ++i)
{
    h_AA[i] = rand()/(float)RAND_MAX;
    h_BB[i] = rand()/(float)RAND_MAX;
}

    for (int i = 0; i < numElements; ++i)
{
    h_Indexx[i] = -1;
}



kernel_wrap(h_AA, h_BB, h_CC, h_Indexx, numElements);

for (int i = 0; i < numElements; ++i)
{

int temp = h_Indexx[i];
if(temp > 0 && temp <= numElements)
{
float tomp = h_AA[temp];
float tom = h_BB[temp];
float to = h_CC[temp];
std::cout << "\n@ i = "<< temp << " is  " << tomp << " + " << tom << " = " << to;
}
}
free(h_AA);
free(h_BB);
free(h_CC);
free(h_Indexx);




return 0;
}
```

And heres how I'm compiling:

```
rm main
rm *.o
g++ -c main.cpp
nvcc -arch=sm_11 -c kernel.cu 
nvcc -o main main.o kernel.o
```

And heres a sample output first with dev_value @ 1.99:

@ i = 39948 is  0.998919 + 0.993153 = 1.99207

then with dev_value @ 1.98:

@ i = 5485 is  0.986223 + 0.995066 = 1.98129

@ i = 1348 is  0.999652 + 0.983039 = 1.98269

@ i = 6921 is  0.992085 + 0.992336 = 1.98442

@ i = 24666 is  0.993531 + 0.994337 = 1.98787

@ i = 27882 is  0.985079 + 0.998244 = 1.98332

@ i = 39948 is  0.998919 + 0.993153 = 1.99207

@ i = 46811 is  0.992908 + 0.993858 = 1.98677

@ i = 47066 is  0.991757 + 0.992284 = 1.98404

Then with dev_value back to 1.99:

@ i = 39948 is  0.998919 + 0.993153 = 1.99207

@ i = 1348 is  0.999652 + 0.983039 = 1.98269

@ i = 6921 is  0.992085 + 0.992336 = 1.98442

@ i = 24666 is  0.993531 + 0.994337 = 1.98787

@ i = 27882 is  0.985079 + 0.998244 = 1.98332

@ i = 39948 is  0.998919 + 0.993153 = 1.99207

@ i = 46811 is  0.992908 + 0.993858 = 1.98677

@ i = 47066 is  0.991757 + 0.992284 = 1.98404

Not sure what is happening, recompiling dosn't fix issue, usually if a change the variable name it begins working again.

Comment: Your code does not compile: `kernel.cu(6): error: identifier "dev_count" is undefined`. I did not look through your code completely, but there are some suspicious things: for example, in `my_push_back()` you assign an `int` to a `double` array.

Comment: If you use CUDA 7.0 or CUDA 7.5 (which you are not, currently) you can add the `-lineinfo` switch to the `nvcc` compile command lines (and delete the `-arch=sm_11` switch - you will need to be running on a cc2.0 or newer device)  Then run your code with `cuda-memcheck --tool initcheck ...`  You will find errors reported due to the usage of improperly initialized memory.

Comment: @havogt, sorry there was a copy paste error, dev_count should exist now.

Comment: @ Robert Crovella-Unfortuntly I don't think I can run CUDA 7.0/7.5 as my GPU won't run on a current enough driver (nvidia gt220 on 340.93 driver) Ill look more into it however, thank you for the help

Comment: You are never initializing the index array on the device to -1.  You set it to -1 on the host side, but you never copy that data to the device.  Add an extra host->device cudaMemcpy operation before your kernel launch, which copies h_Index to d_Index, and I think your problem will be solved.  And, when I do that, all the initcheck errors are gone.  As @havogt said, it's a little odd to use `float` as the type for your index array, but it doesn't present a problem in this case that I can see.

Comment: @ Robert Crovella ah nice catch, not sure why i forgot that, thank you for the help. also, should i delete this question? i have a downvote not sure if i should leave it up

Comment: Why don't you provide an answer (yes, you can answer your own question) explaining what the problem was and how you fixed it.  I will upvote your answer and your question if you do that, which will eliminate the net downvote, and I will remove my close-vote, since the question now approximately contains an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (which it did not originally, and was the reason I close-voted.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Robert Crovella figured out:

You are never initializing the index array on the device to -1. You set it to -1 on the host side, but you never copy that data to the device. Add an extra host->device cudaMemcpy operation before your kernel launch, which copies h_Index to d_Index, and I think your problem will be solved. And, when I do that, all the initcheck errors are gone.

ie i added

```
err = cudaMemcpy(d_Index, h_Index, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```